# Simple HTTP Request not functioning on HTTPS Websites?

Tags: c++, url, networking, https, c++17

I have a website that I need to pull information from, currently I use this code:

```
std::stringstream Output;
IStream* Stream;
HRESULT StreamResult = URLOpenBlockingStream(0, WebsiteLink, &Stream, 0, 0);
if (SUCCEEDED(StreamResult))
{
    char sBuffer[100];
    unsigned long CurrentBRead;

    Stream->Read(sBuffer, 100, &CurrentBRead);
    while (CurrentBRead > 0U)
    {
        Output.write(sBuffer, (long long)CurrentBRead);
        Stream->Read(sBuffer, 100, &CurrentBRead);
    }
    Stream->Release();
    *Return = Output.str();
    return true;
}
```

When I use this on HTTP websites, it functions properly. But when I need to access anything using HTTPS, it just hangs. After some time, I realized that there is a handshake that I must do to authenticate myself with the website, however I don't know how to do this, and all of the solutions online are just "use libcurl".

*Note: I cannot use **ANY** 3rd party libraries*

Comment: You can't use any 3rd-party libraries... so you're saying you're going to write your own SSL/TLS implementation? That sounds fun!

Comment: `URLOpenBlockingStream()` should be handling the necessary TLS handshake for you. Something else is going on to cause the hang. Do you have the same problem if you use the WinInet or WinHTTP API instead? Note that TLS encryption and HTTP authentication are two completely different things.